# how get UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL camera

Tags: iphone, objective-c, camera, uiimagepickercontroller, save

I'm saving an image from the iPhone camera and I manage the delegate method:

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
```

here I need to know:

```
[info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL]
```

but it is always nil if I just took a picture, if different from nil load a picture from the camera roll.
Why is that?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you capture a video, the media is saved on device's storage, and you can access its URL.
If you capture an image, the media is saved into device's memory, and you can access its raw data.

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {
    NSLog(@"%@", info);

    // An image
    if([info[UIImagePickerControllerMediaType] isEqualToString:@"public.image"])
        UIImage *image=info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];

    // A video
    else
        NSURL *url=info[UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL]];
}
```

EDIT: you asked why an image's URL is nil. As you can see, a captured image is never saved on device's storage. One advantage to have picture in memory is that you can process it before storing it on device or sending it over a network.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. In my app, I'm allowing users to either select an image saved in the photo library, or take an image in realtime (that is not saved to the library). When I use `UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL` in order to find the filename of the image saved in the photo library, I am successful, but when I try to do the same for the image captured in realtime, the URL is nil. Do you know what code I can use in order to replicate `UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL` for images that are not saved in the device's storage?